# Is there a function included with Emacs to recursively walk the directory structure and call a function?

Tags: emacs, elisp

I would like to recursively walk down the directory structure from a particular point and call copyright-update-directory at each level.

Is there a function included with Emacs 24 that would help with this? For example something like:

```
(recursive-directory-walk "~/src/foo" '(copyright-update-directory))
```

If no such function exists, some pointers on getting started implementing this (or a working implementation) would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if exists, but not very hard to write your own.

```
(defun folder-dirs (folder)
  (delete-if-not 'file-directory-p
    (mapcar (lambda(arg) (file-name-as-directory (concat (file-name-as-directory folder) arg)))
      (delete-if (lambda (arg) (or (string= ".." arg) (string= "." arg)))
        (directory-files folder)))))

(defun recursively-run-on-every-dir (fn folder)
"FN - function, taking one argument; 
FOLDER - initial forder"
  (funcall fn folder)
  (mapc (lambda(arg) (recursively-run-on-every-dir fn arg))
    (folder-dirs folder))
  nil)

;; use your function instead of print
(recursively-run-on-every-dir 'print "/your/initial/path/")
```

Comment: It seems like this is close, but it doesn't actually run the function on the initial location.

Comment: Also - this does not actually seem to do anything if I use copyright-update-directory as the function, e.g. (copyright-update-directory arg "*"). It prints the names of the directories in the message area, but no copyrights appear to get updated.

Comment: Edited, so it runs on initial location now.
You should pass function of one argument. That argument is absolute path to the folder.

Comment: @wvxvw, not sure how to make BFS without a queue. Lists are maximum inefficient, O(N) per folder. I think there are some libs, but i am too lazy to run through them.

Comment: (setq all-txts '()) (defun remember-txts (folder) (setq all-txts `(,@(txts-in-folder folder) ,@all-txts)) -- works fine with DFS. Not sure what do you mean about "less steps", because number of steps is totally equal - O(Number_of_folders).

Answer (score 4):

The f.el library ([github](https://github.com/rejeep/f.el)) on MELPA contains functions for filesystem traversal.

```
(mapc 'copyright-update-directory (f-directories "~/path" nil t))
```

This will descend the directory hierarchy recursively. See the documentation for [f-directories](https://github.com/rejeep/f.el#f-directories-path-optional-fn-recursive).

Answer (score 3):

Emacs has the build-in function [directory-files-recursively](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Contents-of-Directories.html) for this purpose:

```
(mapc #'YOUR-FUNCTION
      (remove-if-not
       #'file-directory-p       ;only dirs
       (directory-files-recursively YOUR-DIRECTORY "" t)))
```

It's also much faster than the [f-directories](https://github.com/rejeep/f.el#f-directories-path-optional-fn-recursive) function mentioned in the other answer because it doesn't use recursion internal.

Answer (score 2):

Just use `find-lisp`

```
(require 'find-lisp)

;;  a simple function, just to test
(defun my-funct (x)
  (princ x)
  (terpri))

(mapc 'my-funct (find-lisp-find-files "~/src/foo/" "\\.txt$"))
```

Answer (score 1):

I think [Chris Barrett's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19508559/596361) is the correct and idiomatic one. However, for learning purposes i wanted to implement Python's [`os.walk`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk), a general function for breadth-first traversing of directory trees. I used [`dash.el`](https://github.com/magnars/dash.el) list library and [`f.el`](https://github.com/rejeep/f.el) file and directory libraries. This is a stack-based implementation [translated from Python](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/44328/12332).

```
(defun walk (path)
  (let ((stack (list (f-full path)))
        result)
    (while stack
      (let* ((path (pop stack))
             (ds_ (f-directories path))
             (ds (-map 'f-relative ds_))
             (fs (-map 'f-relative (f-files path))))
        (--each ds_ (!cons it stack))
        (!cons (list path ds fs) result)))
    (reverse result)))
```

See functions: [`f-full`](https://github.com/rejeep/f.el#f-full-path), [`pop`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/List-Elements.html#index-pop-317), [`f-directories`](https://github.com/rejeep/f.el#f-directories-path-optional-fn-recursive), [`f-relative`](https://github.com/rejeep/f.el#f-relative-path-optional-dir), [`f-files`](https://github.com/rejeep/f.el#f-files-path-optional-fn-recursive), [`--each`](https://github.com/magnars/dash.el#-each-list-fn), [`!cons`](https://github.com/magnars/dash.el#cons-car-cdr), [`reverse`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Building-Lists.html#index-reverse-336). Now you can use it in loops the same you would use it in Python:

```
(loop for (b ds fs) in (walk path)
      do (copyright-update-directory b "*"))
```